# Matplotlib error when installing Molusce or lifemapper in QGIS Brighton

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, matplotlib

I am installing plugins via the QGIS desktop internal interface, and have had twice now messages associated with matplotlib.  The first error was for something called lifemapper and now for MOLUSCE.  This second plugin is quite popular, so I am not sure if something failed to install properly when I installed the Brighton QGIS software today, or if the plugin is not configured to work with Brighton.

The specific error I get with MOLUSCE is:

> No module named matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.

Comment: I have just installed both and can load the plugin successfully. Try uninstalling the plugin and re-install again. If still not then manually download your plugins from the [repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) and extract the folder to the following directory: **C:\Users\user-name\.qgis2\python\plugins**. Restart QGIS and from the toolbar, go to *Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins...*

Your plugin should be listed, check the box next to the plugin name to enable it.